# Full text search in Google's Cloud Spanner

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Does Cloud Spanner support the `CONTAINS` method or is there a better way to do a full text search on a string?

In the docs I've found `REGEXP_CONTAINS`; is this an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `CONTAINS`, the [operator](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#operators) you are looking for is `LIKE`.

`REGEXP_CONTAINS` is also definitely a method to achieve text search in Cloud Spanner. It allows you to specify regular expressions (supported by the [re2 library](http://code.google.com/p/re2/)).

You may also want to consider `STARTS_WITH` and `ENDS_WITH` if you only want to do prefix or suffix text matching, or `STRPOS` for simple text matching anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the Anwer. I know the LIKE operator but it matches only the whole string. String: "Hello World from Aron" With the LIKE operator i can search "Hello World" but not "Hello Aron" with contains works the second method. I check the other operators. Thank you again

Comment: No problem! You are correct, to match "Hello Aron" you would need to use `REGEXP_CONTAINS` and massage the value to check for into the appropriate regular expression - that is, it does't currently your typical full text search capabilities, but might in the future.

Comment: Thank's! Have great weekend!

Comment: Is there any way to make a `LIKE '%some string%'` query performant ? Using indexes I can't seem to find the solution...

Comment: Best to ask this as a new question @PascalDelange, rather than as a comment

Comment: Right, I'll do that! Thanks